# Laptop screen turns off during startup? 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I restarted my laptop for the first time in a while, rather than just having it hibernate. My computer won't turn on properly now. It turns on, and everything starts going, and it shows a blinking thing in the top left corner, and then the screen turns off. When I press the power key, the screen turns back on again just in time to show the Ubuntu shut down screen with the dots.

I'm able to press F2 when I turn it on. I also somehow accessed the terminal (but I don't know what buttons I pressed to get there...), and it let me log in with my username and password, but I couldn't actually log in to my account from there.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Try booting in recovery mode, to do this:

1. Press shift during startup to get to the grub menu (if you have dual-boot, you don't need to do this)
2. Highlight the option that says "Ubuntu, with linux 3.2.0-41-generic (recovery mode)" or something similar.
3. Press enter to boot from recovery mode.